# clearTimeOut function for not working while using with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that deletes a channel ('general') after 10 min after calling execcmd() function but if the `msg` is sent by someone having 'idofsomeuser' then it should cancel the previous timeout and start the timer again. But it's not working.

```js
function execcmd(msg) {
  let ID = msg.author.id
  let chan = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (channel) => channel.name === 'general'
  );
  x = 'idofsomeuser'
  if (ID == x) {
    clearTimeout(x);
    ID = setTimeout(() => {
      chan.delete();
    }, 600000); //10min 
  } else {
    x = setTimeout(() => {
      chan.delete();
    }, 600000);
  }
}
execcmd(msg); //msg is received by client and passed here
```

Comment: You assign `'idofsomeuser'` to `x` before doing `clearTimeout(x);` in the first `if` statement. So `x` is never a reference to a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [closure function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in which you store the timeout variable. Doing this enables you to store the `timeout` safely without having to create a global variable to store it in.

Inside the callback function first check if the id of the author matches. If it does, clear the timeout and set it to `null`. Then check if the `timeout` is equal to `null` and start the timer.

So now the timer will start when the function is called for the first time, and is restarted everytime the user with the id you're looking for is found.

```
function createClearChannel(channelName, authorId) {
  let timeout = null;
  const timeoutDuration = 1000 * 60 * 10;

  return function (msg) {
    const isAuthor = authorId === msg.author.id;
    const channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(
      channel => channel.name === channelName
    );

    if (isAuthor) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
    }
    
    if (timeout === null) {
      timeout = setTimeout(channel.delete, timoutDuration);
    }
  };
}
```

To set this up, first call the `createClearChannel` function and pass the arguments below. Store the result in `execcmd` and call that function when a message enters.

(You could always omit these parameters and simply hardcode the channel name and id of the user, but by doing this you make the function more flexible so it can be used for other cases as well.)

**Important: The `createClearChannel` should only be called ONCE. So don't create a new `execcmd` when receives each message, but use the same one everytime.**

```
const execcmd = createClearChannel('general', 'idofsomeuser');
execcmd(msg);
```